# Why do I get this error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: getAuth(...).sendPasswordResetEmail is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, vuejs3

I need to implement user login in vue3 with firebase and to send an email to recover the password.

I found the method `sendPasswordResetEmail` in other posts, but each time I tried to make a call I got this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: getAuth(...).sendPasswordResetEmail is not a function

This is my code:

firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth'
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, sendPasswordResetEmail } from 'firebase/auth'


const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIz***",
    authDomain: "beh***",
    databaseURL: "http***",
    projectId: "b***",
    storageBucket: "b***",
    messagingSenderId: "1***",
    appId: "1:*****",
    measurementId: "G-"
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export { app }

export const auth = getAuth(app)

// THIS IS THE METHOD
export const sendEmail = (email) => getAuth().sendPasswordResetEmail(email);

}
```

And, in the other hand, I have my component "SignIn.vue":

```
<template>
    <div class="flex-container widht-sign-up">
        <h1>Registrate</h1>
        <Text :title="'Email'"></Text>
        <InputTextComponent required style="height: 40px;" @input="updateEmail"></InputTextComponent>
        <Text style="margin-top: 20px;" :title="'Contraseña'"></Text>
        <InputTextComponent required style="height: 40px;" @input="updatePassWord"></InputTextComponent>
        <Button style="margin-top: 20px;" class="btn btn-primary" :title="'Enviar'" @handleButtonClick="signUp"></Button>
    </div>
</template>
    
<script>
import { createUserWithEmail, sendEmail } from '../firebase'
import Text from '../components/TextDisplayComponent.vue';
import InputTextComponent from "../components/InputTextComponent.vue"
import Button from '../components/Button.vue';
export default {
    components: {
        Text,
        InputTextComponent,
        Button
    },
    data() {
        return {
            email: '',
            password: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updateEmail(email) {
            this.email = this.formatInput(email)
        },
        updatePassWord(password) {
            this.password = this.formatInput(password)
        },
        signUp() {
            // HERE I WANT TO CALL MY METHOD
            sendEmail(this.email).then((p) => {})
           
        },
        formatInput(event) {
            const pepe = event instanceof Event ? event.target.value : event;
            return pepe
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sendPasswordResetEmail` is its own function in the new modular v9 API.  It's not a method on the object returned by `getAuth()` as it was in older versions.  In fact, you imported the function already:

```
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, sendPasswordResetEmail } from 'firebase/auth'
```

Now just call it as you see in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_password_reset_email):

```
sendPasswordResetEmail(getAuth(), email);
```

Comment: Thanks!!, the error go away, thus the email never came. Neverheless you helped me.